# make computer wake up at time

Tags: macos, applications, launchd, software

I'm working on a project that involves using launchd at a certain time. I have heard that launchd will only work if the computer is awake/logged in. **What is the best way to insure that launchd will launch an application at midnight?** I am running macOS 10.15.4

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule your Mac to wake up at a specific time every day, such as 11:57 p.m. by using the Schedule... function in the Energy Saver panel in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: I did this, but can you confirm that an app can be launched?

Comment: hmmm I will try this 
--
thanks